# Title block with circuitikz

Tags: captions, circuitikz

To an electric circuit schematic I've made in `circuitikz`, I'd like to add a title block like the one given here, including logo if possible. I've searched the web for "LaTeX title block" as well as this forum, but not finding what I need.

I'm so new to LaTeX that I have to use Overleaf to generate schematics although I've installed TexWorks on my Fujitsu engineering laptop I can only yet make errors with it, but that's another story altogether methinks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! To me this looks like an ordinary table, which has not much to do with `circuitikz`.

Comment: You might also look at PDF form packages, like hyperref and  eforms.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494998/circuitikz-how-to-create-professional-wiring-diagram-borders/495142#495142