# CircuiTikZ: How to create professional wiring diagram borders?

Tags: header-footer, tikz-styles, circuitikz, border, footer

Assumed we have this **Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
        \draw (0,0) to [battery={info={$e_1$}}] ++(10,0)
        to [current direction' = {info = {$i$}, near start}, resistor = {info = {$R$}, near end}] ++(0,10)
        to [bulb] ++(-10,0) to[current direction' = {info = {$i$}}] (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

As you can see, this is just an ugly whitepage. Would it be possible to add some nice page borders containing document information to let the sheet appear a bit more professional?

I would dream about some nice borders based on the following ideas.

---

**Screenshots of nice wiring diagram borders:**

[image: Screenshot of a professional wiring diagram 2]

[image: Screenshot of a professional wiring diagram 1]

---

Maybe there is some good template available to upstyle the initial wiring diagram to improve its appearance?

Comment: In technical language that is called a title block. There was already [this same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/478675/50910), with no answers though.

Comment: You are not using `circuitikz` in your example. Anyway, both it and the circuit library are just drawing; you can use boxes and matrix to draw this kind of things. If your question is if there are pre-made template, I think the answer is no.

Comment: This look like a company or possibly government dependent form.  So unless whoever specified the form has a template, odds are against it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as a starting point: you can use absolute page coordinate (see [Positioning relative to page in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89588/positioning-relative-to-page-in-tikz)) and overlays, together with a bit of coordinate labeling...

```latex
\documentclass[]{report}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[a3paper, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw (current page.center)  ++(-20,14) coordinate (NW) % using 40x28cm
        -- ++(40,0) coordinate (NE)
        -- ++(0,-28) coordinate (SE)
        -- ++(-40,0) coordinate (SW)
        -- cycle;
    \foreach \x in {0,5,...,35}
         \draw (NW) ++(\x,0) rectangle ++(5,-1) ++(-2.5, 0.5) node[]{\x};
    \node [draw, anchor=south east, align=left, font=\Huge, inner sep=12pt] 
        at(SE) {Drawn by yours truly\\Romano};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{circuitikz}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw (current page.center) node[op amp](A3){} (A3.+) -- ++(0,-0.5) node[ground]{};
        \draw (A3.-) to[R, l_=$R$, name=c3] ++(-2,0) coordinate(in) (A3.-) -- ++(0,1)
        coordinate(tmp) to[R, l_=$R$] (tmp-|A3.out) -- (A3.out) -- ++(1,0) node[midway, above]{out} ;
        \draw (in) node[op amp, noinv input up, anchor=out](B){} (B.-) -- ++(0,-1) coordinate(tmp) -- (tmp-|B.out) -- (B.out);
        \draw (B.+) -- ++(-0.5,0) node[midway, above]{in};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: big A3 page with sub-boxes]

Comment: This is awesome, thank you very much! Would it be possible to replace the precise `\x` text with `symbolic x coords` like `T1`, `T2`, ... , `T5` (instead of the current measuring value `0`, `5`, ... , `35`)?

Comment: Yes, of course. `\foreach` is very powerful; look at the manual (TikZ manual, section 83, page 900 in version 3.0.1a). Try: `\foreach \x [count=\i from 1] in {0,5,...,35}   \draw (NW) ++(\x,0) rectangle ++(5,-1) ++(-2.5, 0.5) node[]{T\i};`

Comment: Wow, this is nice! Thank you! :-)